# Invoke SignalR server side methods from services

Tags: c#, signalr

I have architecture similar that at the diagram below. I wonder hot to invoke hub operations on `SignalR server` (which is separate IIS application) from my services (also separate applications - `windows service`). In other words I want to push notification from my `services` to `WebClients` through the `SignalR server`. Is using `.NET SignalR clients` in services the only way to do this ? What if i want to use `[Authorize]` attribute on `Hub` methods ? After that I will have to create separate users for my services ?

```
 ___________             ___________              ___________
|           |           |           |            |           |
|           |---------->|           |            |           |
| WebClient |           |  SignalR  |<-----------| Service1  |
|           |<----------|           |            |           |
|___________|           |___________|            |___________|
                             .
                            /|\
                             |
                             |
                         ___________             
                        |           |
                        |           |
                        | Service2  |           
                        |           |           
                        |___________|
```

Comment: You can use the .Net client to connect and invoke a method on the hub. What types are service1 and 2?

Comment: They are windows services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the .NET client library within the windows services. They will behave in the same manner as any other SignalR client.

There are many comprehensive examples for SignalR over at asp.net/signalr.

[Authentication options for .NET clients](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/security/hub-authorization#authoptions)

One way to do a authentication will be to have a separate page to just set the authentication cookie, and then pick up the cookie from the `Response`, and then use that within the running windows service instance when performing calls to methods on the `Hub` which is decorated with `[Authorize]`.

Code snippet from documentation:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var connection = new HubConnection("http://www.contoso.com/");
        Cookie returnedCookie;

        Console.Write("Enter user name: ");
        string username = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Enter password: ");
        string password = Console.ReadLine();

        var authResult = AuthenticateUser(username, password, out returnedCookie);

        if (authResult)
        {
            connection.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            connection.CookieContainer.Add(returnedCookie);
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome " + username);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Login failed");
        }    
    }

    private static bool AuthenticateUser(string user, string password, out Cookie authCookie)
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.contoso.com/RemoteLogin") as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

        var authCredentials = "UserName=" + user + "&Password=" + password;
        byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authCredentials);
        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }

        using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            authCookie = response.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        }

        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Snippet for https://www.contoso.com/RemoteLogin (used in the above example):

```
namespace SignalRWithConsoleChat
{
    public partial class RemoteLogin : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string username = Request["UserName"];
            string password = Request["Password"];
            bool result = Membership.ValidateUser(username, password);
            if (result)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```